# About the Spring RMI running in Linux system

Tags: java, linux, spring, rmi

When I packed my RMI applications and moved to Linux system and ran it.

The log shows that RMI services are running on server 127.0.0.1(Which was printed by method of `InetAddress.getLocalhost()).`

The configuration in Host file is "127.0.0.1    localhost.localdomain localhost", so I think RMI server was defalutly got the Localhost as servering IP.

After that, my RMI client try to invoke the RMI server method with its real IP(172.16.7.155) which caused a exception "Refused to connect 127.0.0.1".

There're two ways to reslove this problem. The one is modify Host file and reflect the localhost to real IP(172.16.7.155), but I can not modify it because other applications are using localhost domain.

Another way is to reset the method of fecthing IP address at RMI Server, i.e. instead the `InetAddress.getLocalhost()`, is there any configuration for this method?

Answer (score 0):

You can probably fix this by starting your java rmi server process with the system property "-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=172.16.7.155" (or whatever the public ip of the box is).  (details [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/rmi/javarmiproperties.html))